# How to autorotate game scene in landscape right and landscape left mode in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos box2d version v1.1.0-RC0. Can anyone please help me out that how could i auto rotate my game scene in both landscape right and landscape left mode.Game scene oriented only in landscape left but not rotated in landscape right with device orientation.

Comment: Are both landscape left and landscape right enabled in your target's summary page (info.plist)?

Comment: @Sylvan -  Yes, both landscape left and landscape right enabled in your target's summary page (info.plist).